# remove cells in "Allow users to edit ranges" of xls sheet using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to protect sheets in my xls file so that all locked cells become    uneditable when `Sheet#protectSheet()` is called. all the locked cells are becoming uneditable except for one; The reason this one cell is editable even though  it is locked and `Sheet#protectSheet()` is called on that sheet is this cell is added to "Allow users to edit ranges" which is under "Review" tab. is it possible to programmatically remove this cell from "Allow users to edit ranges" in apache POI. I have gone through their documentation but failed to find an API for this. or is there any work around?

Comment: For `XSSF` aka Office Open XML = `*.xlsx` this would be [CTWorksheet.getProtectedRanges](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTWorksheet.java#CTWorksheet.getProtectedRanges%28%29). So even if not directly available from `apache poi`until now, it would be solvable using the low level objects.

Comment: But for `HSSF` aka `BIFF` = `*.xls` this seems to be [BIFF8 - RANGEPROTECTION](https://www.openoffice.org/sc/excelfileformat.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A611%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C85.6%2C350.3%2C0%5D). And for this even OpenOffice says only `2do` = to do.